# CSV File format

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created an csv file with the following values
10.25,10.35,10.45

One of the example is in german language decimal seperators are , and comma seperated values are ;

Apart from this is there any other difference in the CSV format.

Comment: What do you mean difference? If you are parsing a CSV by specifying the delimiter, I don't think the particular culture would matter. Or, perhaps, I should say, if a delimiter character is likely to be identical to a valid character in data, the CSV file should probably wrap text in quotes or so.

Comment: If you import this file using, in the windows 7 with the regional settings as German. Will this matter?

Comment: open the excel, click on the data tab. It has another tab, from the text.Using this option I am trying to import the csv file.

Comment: Note that in windows region settings, up to theree characters can be used as a separator.

Comment: If you specify delimiter as a comma, it will split by comma.